# Single line while loop in algorithm

Tags: algorithm2e

I am using Algorithm2E and I find myself in a situation where I want to express `while(!condition);`, but I cannot do that on a single line, it seems. This is the closest I got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[linesnumbered, ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetKwFunction{KwCrit}{critcalSection}
\SetKwFunction{Kwtas}{test-and-set}
\While{$\Kwtas(r) = 1$}{ }
\KwCrit()\\
$r \gets 0$\\
\caption{Pseudocode of test-and-set usage}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

But this puts a single line containing only end. It expresses what I want, but looks quite dirty. How would I be able to express this on a single line?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every code construction `\<code>` that puts its content on multiple lines, there is an accompanying `\l<code>` that puts the content on a single line. You can also define your own `\WHILE` (and accompanying `\lWHILE`) using `\SetKwFor{<macro>}{<start cond>}{<end cond>}{<end construct>}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\SetKwFor{WHILE}{while (}{)}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetKwFunction{KwCrit}{criticalSection}
  \SetKwFunction{Kwtas}{test-and-set}
  \lWhile{$\Kwtas{r} = 1$}{}
  \lWHILE{$\Kwtas{r} = 1$}{}
  \KwCrit{}\;
  $r \gets 0$\;
  \caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```